# 1 rep user, first post is controversial

Tags: discussion, specific-question, trolling

[Can a manager speak to her husband about my work life?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/113565/can-a-manager-speak-to-her-husband-about-my-work-life)

I'm pretty sure this isn't a serious question.

Answer (score 5):

Serious or not, this post is highly unclear (thus why it got closed).

However, there are some inconsistencies and issues that suggest this may be indeed a fake post:

- **The title and questions don't match the same target**. First the title says *"speak to her husband about **my** work life"*... but then it switches to *the OP's husband*...
- The fact that the manager (apparently a woman) talked about an employee's life with her husband has **no connection whatsoever with the rest of the post**. Is this about harassment? About speaking about employee's life? Unclear. Perhaps it was added to fuel the post's controversy.
- **Freshly made user**, hasn't even bothered taking the tour.
- <s>2</s>...22 hours after the posting the user **neglects giving any feedback** at all or addressing any other questions made to clarify in comments.

IMHO, these sort of posts do not bring anything good to the Community, and should be closed, if not deleted.

Comment: +1 The rule around here is that it doesn't matter if you suspect trolling, treat the question based on its content (or lack thereof in this case).

Comment: @DavidK yeah, but if the question isn't serious, it should be deleted, as opposed to just closed.

Comment: @Crossedtheriverstyx Yes, but how do you determine what is and isn't serious? I think it's likely the OP of this question is being completely serious - they just have a poor grasp of English and are not clearly communicating their problem.

Comment: @DavidK The most obvious cases are just that, and there are clear indicators, as outlined above.  Poor English, is one thing, a new user, is one thing, neglecting feedback is one thing.  Combined, it's a clear example.  So, I guess what determines what is serious is the number of red flags.  This one has more than the Chinese government had on display during the olympics